# Can a TextView have both background and image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-relativelayout, textview

Basically the other option I am considering is a RelativeLayout with a background. Then inside the layout, have the image to the left and the text to the right. I think I read somewhere that I can have a TextView with an accompanying image. So I am wondering if what I want is possible with one textview?

- The background would be a rounded-rectangle of a certain color
- The image would be on the left
- The text would be on the right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yup, you can do this all in a TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/my_image"
    android:background="@drawable/my_rounded_corners"
    android:text="@string/my_text" />
```

There's also a `drawablePadding` attribute to adjust spacing between the text and the drawable. There's not a lot of fine tuning of the position of the drawable, so if you need something more precise you'll have to go with individual views, but this works well for a lot of cases.